# D3 tickFormat error stating n.getMonth is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am using D3 to create a line graph of some data. I am passing it a date in ms and I want to display it in hours and minutes. I have tried passing it the value as a return of new Date(myDate), which also doesn't work.

Here is the error I am getting when I run. "Uncaught TypeError: n.getMonth is not a function"

I have also tried to convert all the ms time based by running them through new Date(time), but nothing changed.

Here's my graph code. variable time refers to an array of ms based time measurements.

```
    function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
var lines = [];
for(var i =1, arrayLen = allTextLines.length; i<arrayLen; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    if (data.length === headers.length) {
        lines.push({time: Date.parse(data[0]), last: data[1]});
    }
}
var final = []
var d3Formater = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");
for(var i = lines.length-1, base = (lines[lines.length-1].time - 14400001); i>0; i--) {
    if(lines[i].time>base) {

        var temp = new Date(lines[i].time)
        console.log(temp);
        final.push(d3Formater.parse(temp));
    }
}
delete lines;
var xMin = new Date(d3.min(time));
var xMax = new Date(d3.max(time));

var vis = d3.select("#visualization"),
    WIDTH = 1000,
    HEIGHT = 500,
    MARGINS = {
       top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 50
    },
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([xMin, xMax]),
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([yMin, yMax]),

        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m-%d")),

        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to parse the date into a `Date` object. How are you doing that?

Comment: Ok, so where are you getting `time` from? You would need to parse all of the dates, not just the max and min.

Comment: I included the rest of the code. All the dates have been parsed. The max and the min were just converted back to normal, readable notation. Do all of them need to be?

Comment: The data starts as a csv with times and values.

Comment: And what format is your time data in in the CSV? What I'm getting at is that the time is probably not parsed properly.

Comment: What definition of parse do you mean? because Date.parse() is what I used on every single entry. So all the dates are turned into ms denomination.

Comment: `Date.parse()` may or may not work properly depending on the format of the string and the browser. It's much safer to use D3's date parsing methods and specify the format explicitly.

Comment: I edited the for loop that I use for the graph later. I define the date using the new Date(). and define a d3 style time formater. Where that console.log(temp) is prints outs this (Thu May 07 2015 17:16:58 GMT-0400 (EDT)) . Then it fails as for d3 with error: Uncaught TypeError: t.slice is not a function. Is that really d3 not working on the format? As I would assume that is standard new Date() format.

Comment: I have the times working now with this line: time.push(d3Formater(new Date(lines[i].time))); 

Should be able to get the rest of it working. 

Thank you so much for continuing to follow through with respones 17 hours laters.

Comment: My point is that you're using the `Date` constructor to "parse" the strings, which may break at any point. It's much better to use D3 to parse (not just format) the date, see the `parse` method [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
xScale = d3.scale.linear()....
```

Try using...

```
xScale = d3.time.scale()....
```