# Uncaught TypeError: n.getMonth is not a function in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, json, date, d3.js

I am getting an error, I suspect with the date objects, from a json file which is being read via d3.

I am basing the code on this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768

I have modified this to read a json file, rather than a tsv. The function should read in the json, then run a function called type(), which should read the date strings from the json and parse them into date objects.

I have created an example at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/5vkqugsa/)

My function looks like this:

```
var dataURL = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/x9e87';
var timeOfDay = ["Before 03:00","Before 08:00","Before 10:00", "Before 15:00", "Before 17:00","Before 23:59"];
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scale.category20();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("right");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json(dataURL, function(error, ingestionAmount) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var layers = d3.layout.stack()(timeOfDay.map(function(c) {
    return ingestionAmount.map(function(d) {
      return {x: d.date, y: d[c]};
    });
  }));

  x.domain(layers[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]).nice();

  var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

  layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.y0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis);

      type();
});

function type(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  timeOfDay.forEach(function(c) { d[c] = +d[c]; });
  return d;
}
```

My json is straightforward (the full file is available here https://api.myjson.com/bins/x9e87)

```
[  
   {  
      "date":"11/11/2017",
      "Before 03:00":31,
      "Before 08:00":5,
      "Before 10:00":44,
      "Before 15:00":18,
      "Before 17:00":98,
      "Before 23:59":12
   },
   {  
      "date":"12/11/2017",
      "Before 03:00":30,
      "Before 08:00":3,
      "Before 10:00":67,
      "Before 15:00":4,
      "Before 17:00":24,
      "Before 23:59":33
   },
{ ///
]
```

I thought perhaps d3 was specific about date formats, so I added hours, minutes and seconds, but this made no difference. I also found [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970921/1238244) which suggests changing the d3 scale function. Again this did not work. I am parsing the date in the way that d3 should expect `"%d/%m/%Y"` it so I cannot work out what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo: [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5vkqugsa/6/)

The way the "type" function is being called is incorrect. If you debug the chart at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768, you'll see that every element from the array "crimea" is parsed and formatted in the `type` function.

Now that `d3.json` has no `accessor` argument where in you can pass `type` function as we can do in `d3.csv(function(<filename>, type, callback){})` , we'll have to do it manually.

**Relevant code:**

Parse every element of array:

```
ingestionAmount.forEach(function(d) {
  type(d);
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Yes! that's great thank you. I had noticed I could not pass the type function into the d3.json function but wasn't sure how to initiate it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)